# How to use http4k-jsonrpc from http4k project?

Tags: kotlin, json-rpc, http4k

According http4k documentation to configure JSON-RPC server I should use JsonRpc.auto or JsonRpc.manual, but unfortunately I can't find any example. API doc contains something like:

```
fun <NODE : Any> auto(json: JsonLibAutoMarshallingJson<NODE>, errorHandler: ErrorHandler = defaultErrorHandler, fn: Auto<NODE>.() -> Unit): JsonRpcService<NODE>
```

and I don't know, which implementations of interfaces I should use.

```
fun main() {
    val app: HttpHandler = JsonRpc.auto(???)
    app.asServer(Jetty(8080)).start()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there were some missing docs. There is now an example on the site, but in future the best port of call is to look at the tests first. :)

Here's the example:
https://www.http4k.org/guide/modules/jsonrpc/

Comment: Thank you for this example! You are right about tests, of course, but this example is more understandable for beginners in Kotlin.